# Does Internet Explorer 10 on Windows RT support Flash for all websites?

Tags: flash, windows-8, internet-explorer-10

**Update**: This has now changed. Flash will be supported on both Windows RT and Windows 8 *unless* explicitly blacklisted. Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2013/03/11/flash-in-windows-8.aspx

I have a Flash based website and I want it to run on IE10 on Windows RT. After searching I do not know if it will.

Here's what I know:

- Microsoft maintain an **[IE10 Flash Compatibility List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj193557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** which is a list of sites for which Flash will work for both IE10 Modern UI mode and IE10 Desktop mode on Windows RT and Windows 8.
- My site is not on the compatibility list ([iecompatdata.xml](https://gist.github.com/3860056)).

In the documentation it is not clear whether Flash should be supported in Windows RT for websites **not on the compatibility list**. This is due, in part, to the lack of distinction between "Windows 8" and "Windows RT"

For example ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj193557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)):

> **About Compatibility View list**
>
> While any site can play Flash content in Internet Explorer 10 for the desktop, only sites that are on the Compatibility View (CV) list for Flash can play Flash content within Internet Explorer 10 in the the new Windows UI.

Here I am not sure if "Internet Explorer 10 for the desktop" includes Windows RT IE10 running in Desktop mode or not.

To those saying "Windows RT does not have desktop mode" - this is not correct, Windows RT has desktop mode but *only* for IE10 and Microsoft Office.

Comment: How did you consult the compatibility list ? (you say your site is not on this list)

Comment: By opening `File:\\%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\IECompatData\iecompatdata.xml` on Windows 8. I have made this file available here: https://gist.github.com/3860056

Answer (score 5):

Windows RT ships with Flash Player version 11.3.xx but it is available only to whitelisted sites in BOTH Metro (Windows UI) and Desktop modes. This differs from the regular version of Windows 8 for Intel machines where whitelisting is required only for Metro mode.

In order for your Flash-based content to render on a Windows RT device in either mode you must apply for and be accepted for certification, info for which may be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj193557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: As of today the truth of this answer has changed - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2013/03/11/flash-in-windows-8.aspx. @Konrad want to update?

Answer (score 1):

I think you only need to parse this the correct way and keep the terminology straight.

Windows RT is the version of Windows 8 which only runs on ARM devices and is limited to using the UI formerly known as Metro, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_RT.

The IE10 running in the new Windows 8 style UI (Metro) is a special Windows Store app available on all Windows 8 machines, it is not limited to Windows RT devices. The IE10 for the desktop is the full version of IE which will continue to support the full functionailty of IE. It is only available when you are in the Desktop mode, and as a result it is not available on ARM devices running Windows RT.

So there is no such thing as "Windows RT IE 10 running in Desktop mode". It is either Metro IE10 or IE10 for the desktop.

I've been digging around the net for a while to try to confirm if IE10 will be available for Windows 7. The best I found was on MSDN, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673549(v=vs.85).aspx. This means that IE10 (for desktop) will be available both for Windows 7 and Windows 8.

Comment: But you can run IE10 in Desktop mode on a Windows RT device - desktop mode on Win RT is supported for IE and Office. This (presumably) differs from the desktop mode on Windows 8 non-rt.

Comment: I talked to some friends about this and they confirm that you are correct! I had gotten that part of the Windows RT story wrong, there is a Desktop in Windows RT but you cannot install non-Windows Store apps.

Comment: Indeed, this is why it gets confusing! At first glance it appears that there is no desktop mode in Windows RT but when you look a little deeper there *is*, but only for IE+Office.

Comment: To upvoters please note that this is not the right answer, Windows RT *does have Desktop mode* (for IE10, at least) so the definition is still unclear.